# allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, exception, web-config

This is the error i get:

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.

I can view the site on the server as localhost or ip and it works. If you browse to the server from another computer i get the error message.

I deleted the bin folder, republished the application, made a clean build: still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the folder you published to isn't set up as an Application in IIS.